# Symfony2 form - how overwrite field with default value

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I have a form with one default value:

```
class GearType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('options')
            ->add('model', 'choice', array('choices' => $this->getModelChoices(), 'data' => 2));
    }
```

one of the requirements is form can be pre-populated by re-sellers by passing parameters in URL. It is also nice feature for potential customers to copy and paste link to email, communicators, etc.

I did it this way:

```
    /**
 * @Route("/car/gear")
 * @Template()
 */
public function gearAction(Request $request)
{
    $form = $this->createForm(new GearType());

    if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
        $form->bind($request);
        if ($form->isValid()) {
            return 'is valid';
        }
    } else {
        $get = $this->getRequest()->query->all();
        if (!empty($get)) {
            $normalizer = new GetSetMethodNormalizer();
            $form->setData($normalizer->denormalize($get, new Gear())); # look here 
        }
    }

    return array('form' => $form->createView());
}
```

unfortunately field 'options' has always default value, instead value passed as a parameter.
I have tried to change line # look here into

```
        $gear =  $normalizer->denormalize($get, new Gear());
        $form = $this->createForm(new GearType(), $gear);
```

but no result.

It seems that solution is passing additional parameter to GearType object. I do not like this solution. Does anyone know better way?

Answer (score 0):

Add this snippet, and modifiy between the [ ] as appropriate

```
        $form->bind($request);
        if ( [ passed parameters from querystring ] ){               //// New Code
            $form->getData()->setOptions( [ processed parameter ]);  //// New Code 
        }                                                            //// New Code
        if ($form->isValid()) {
            return 'is valid';
        }
```

Comment: Unfortunately not - it causes  Fatal error: Call to undefined method Symfony\Component\Form\Form::setOptions()

Comment: My apologies, I forgot the getData() call to $form.  edited above.

Comment: $form->getData() returns null or my entity (when I bind request and turn CSRF off) - they still does not have setOptions method

Comment: setOptions would be in your entity code.  It is possible you should use addOptions based on the association mapping.  Can only guess without seeing more code (entity/doctrine mapping)

Comment: My entity is just POPO, only properties, setters and getters. There are no any options.

Comment: I got an answer https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/7141#issuecomment-13863649

Comment: 'options' is one of your properties.  Each gear has 'options' according to your form type.  If your gear has no options property, why are you passing it to the form?

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the field `options` always having default value may be the actual query. Instead of denormalizing and setting the data directly, modify `else` fragment to:

```
} else {
    $form = $this->createForm(new GearType(), new Gear(), array(
        'validation_groups' => array('not-validating')
    ));
    $form->bind($request);
}
```

The form will validate only against validations associated with the `not-validating` group, which will avoid showing the common `required` alerts if the form is built form `GET`.

Docs about 'validations-groups': http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#validation-groups

The question is similar to: [Entity form field and validation in Symfony2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8988718/entity-form-field-and-validation-in-symfony2)